# how can I make airmon-ng work with broadcom 14e4:43a0 bcm4360 chip

Tags: 16.04, broadcom, airmon-ng

I have been having a problem getting my wireless chip to work with Airmon-ng.

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as a dual boot with macbook air. These are a few outputs:

```
ifconfig:
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:2762 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2762 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:274961 (274.9 KB)  TX bytes:274961 (274.9 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
      inet addr:192.168.xxx.xxx  Bcast:192.168.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::9a98:9d45:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: fe80::52ea:ddc5:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: fe80::9d40:7a9:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:9451 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1576
      TX packets:7435 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:10570224 (10.5 MB)  TX bytes:704183 (704.1 KB)
      Interrupt:18 

iwconfig:
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Slingshot Home WIFI 528"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 94:FB:B2:xx:xx:xx   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off

lspci -nn -d 14e4:
02:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)

sudo airmon-ng start wlp3s0:

Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID Name
726 avahi-daemon
761 avahi-daemon
812 NetworkManager
942 wpa_supplicant
3200    dhclient
Process with PID 3200 (dhclient) is running on interface wlp3s0

Interface   Chipset     Driver

wlp3s0      Broadcom    wl - [phy1]mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

            (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

I´ve been trying to fix this problem for about 3 days with no success. I´m starting to think I may need a USB wireless adapter. I´d rather not.

if you need any further information, I will put up whatever you need.